# Nextjs - getting cookies value on _app init

Tags: cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I need to get the cookies value on the first render. I get those in _app.tsx.
Everything looks fine (render correctly the html) but I get the server/client mismatch warning because at the first render on Server, cookies are undefined and the value fall back to default value which is 0.
On hydration, the value is picked from cookies and is displayed correctly.

Could someone explain to me why is a problem that on the server the value is the default value (therefor why I get this warning) and what would be a better way to write this code?

Here my _app.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { UserContext } from '../context/UserContext'
require('es6-promise').polyfill()

let cookieHelper
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  cookieHelper = require( '../helpers/_cookies' ) // This is a file written by us where we export const and get/set cookies func 
}

function ElliotApp ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    import('../helpers/_cookies')
  }, [])
  
  const searchesFromCookies = cookieHelper?.get(cookieHelper?.COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT) // this value is a string like '3'
  const userState = { 
    numOfSearches: searchesFromCookies || 0 
  }
  const [userContext, setUserContext] = useState(userState)

  useEffect(() => {
    cookieHelper?.set(cookieHelper?.COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT, userContext.numOfSearches)
  }, [userContext])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[userContext, setUserContext]}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ElliotApp
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone explain to me why is a problem that on the server the value is the default value

Probably because your `cookieHelper` is just reading cookies from `document.cookie` and there is no such thing on the server.

If you want to get cookie with SSR you could use `getInitialProps`:

```
function parseCookies(req) {
  // cookie.parse is some function that accepts cookie string and return parsed object
  return cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || "" : document.cookie)
}


ElliotApp.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const cookies = parseCookies(req)

  return {
    searchesFromCookies: cookies[COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT]
  }
}
```

and then do something with them in your App component:

```
function ElliotApp ({ Component, pageProps, searchesFromCookies }: AppProps) {
  const userState = { 
    numOfSearches: searchesFromCookies || 0 
  }
  const [userContext, setUserContext] = useState(userState)

  // do whatever ...
}
```

EDIT:

In case you are fine with default value on the server then you just need to do everything inside `useEffect` hook (it wont run on the server):

```
function ElliotApp ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const userState = { 
    numOfSearches: 0 
  }
  const [userContext, setUserContext] = useState(userState)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserContext({
      numOfSearches: cookieHelper.get(cookieHelper.COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT)
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    cookieHelper.set(cookieHelper.COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT, userContext.numOfSearches)
  }, [userContext])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[userContext, setUserContext]}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your replay :) I'm aware that I cannot get cookies on the server side and I don't want to. I'm fine with getting a default cookies value .i.e. 0 on server and then update it later on the client with hydration. But I still get this warning that tells me there is a value mismatch from server to client and I wonder why is this a problem. 
Why is a problem that there is a mismatch? Isn't common to update a value in a second moment, at a second render? That's my actual question..

Comment: Also, my understanding is that getInitialProps will be deprecated soon, isn't it?
And it will make all my pages SSR, not sure I want that.

Comment: I updated my answer with different way which uses `useEffect`. 

Well, mismatch is something unexpected, there will be unnecessary re render and flash of default state which makes SSR kinda useless for that case. And it is not really common to do that, although sometimes you cannot do anything else. If `getInitialProps` will be deprecated then there will be something else so nothing to worry about. But you are right that if you use it with `CustomApp` it will make your whole application dynamic.